# nginx forwarding from another server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I host a website using Linode ([UnixUniverse.net](http://unixuniverse.net)) and would like to share some files from my home server, which is of course on a different IP. Sorry for the noob question, I'm quite new to nginx and proxying.

Basically, I want to have files.unixuniverse.net (and if possible ftp.unixuniverse.net) point to my home server with a directory browser. Would the best way be to mount the home server using an NFS mount/fuse, or is there a better way of doing it? Understandably, I wish to do this to not expose my home ip to the internet but still be able to share isos and software builds that would take up too much space on my 25gb VM host.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at multiple backends for the same frontend configuration for nginx?

Comment: I've checked into it but I'm completely new to nginx so all the options are confusing. Basically I'm wondering how to set up ftp.unixuniverse.net and files.unixuniverse.net with directory listing but I'm not sure how to set up these subdomains.